# Error trying to import 'systemjs' to use import dynamically

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, systemjs, es6-modules

I am trying to use SystemJS to import a module that lives on an external server.  Having problems just getting started with importing systemjs so that I can use it in code.

```
import System from 'systemjs';
OR 
import * as System from 'systemjs';

// System not found, error on line above trying to import systemjs as module.
System.import('https://test.com/modules/somemodule.js').then(module => {
  // got the module
});
```

Neither work.  This is all assuming its possible to use System.import(...) in code to import a module.  Reading through the docs not really sure how to import systemjs.

**Error:**
*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'systemjs'*

Comment: You're missing a closing quote at the end of this line: `import * as System from 'systemjs;`

Comment: Add a `catch` clause and see what the error is; if the external JavaScript file lives on a remote server, the server must serve the file as a static resource.

Comment: Its not a problem with trying to import the dynamic module, I don't get that far.  See updated question, I get an error on the 1st line trying to import systemjs.

Comment: It seems like a transpilation lapse. Try `const Global  = require('systemjs/dist/extras/global')` or `import * as Global from 'systemjs/dist/extras/global'` and then `Global.import()`. [Their documentation](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#extras) does mention doing something like this.

Comment: Seems no matter what I do it cannot find systemjs as a package.  If I go directly to node_modules to force it to look there its fine.  require('node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js.min').  What gives?

Comment: @lostintranslation - were you able to find solution for this?